# Can't install Android SDK platforms

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-16.04, android-sdk-2.3

When installing Android platforms (different Android API's) I get the following message:

`Installation did not complete successfully. See logs for details.`

I use Ubuntu 16.04 (best working Ubuntu for me).
I tried to use the default location (*.../Android/Sdk*) and install them into different location, tried to reboot system - makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in /tmp - it was too small because of size of root partition, root parition had size of  15Gb, I had to extend it to 20Gb.